# Has Ruby a keyword `define`?

Tags: ruby

Where can I find the documentation for `define` (see snippet below) in Ruby?

```
define :brew do
   package @name,
   :ensure   => :present,
   :provider => :homebrew,
   :require  => "Vcsrepo[/usr/local]"
end
```

I am not sure whether it is a Ruby keyword actually.

Comment: if you're looking for how to store a block in a variable, see `Proc.new` or the literal syntax for lambdas (`->()`, I think). To use a proc as a block, use `&`.

Comment: This `define` is probably a method name, with `:brew` as argument and followed by a block.

Comment: `def brew; your code; end` will do, no `define`.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't it make sense to tell people *where* you saw the snippet, to provide context?

It's likely you're looking at a Puppet script:

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/index.html

The place to find the definition of `define`, then, is in the [Puppet source](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet).

Comment: Yes, it would help. Sorry. Yes, I am looking at a Puppet script.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a ruby keyword, you can find a list of ruby keyword in http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/